# What are the limitations of System.runAs?

Tags: apex, unit-test, system.runas

Unfortunately it seems that there is some undocumented behaviour with System.runAs and creating users in Apex tests. In particular we observed, with API 45:

1. If we run a test class that we do not define `without sharing` if we pass the ProfileId in the constructor to the new User, this is not saved.
2. If we try to set it later in a test class not defined `without sharing` after like so `user1.ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'].Id` we get an error that says that `ProfileId is not writeable`
3. If we try in a class that has a `without sharing` then we get an error when we invoke System.runAs: `REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [ProfileId]: [ProfileId]`

Here, for example, the code of the first case:

```
public class UserTest {

private static User buildUser(Profile p, String username, String alias){
    User user1 =  new User(Alias = alias, Username=username, LastName ='LM', 
     Email='example@example-213213.com',
     EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
     LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
     LocaleSidKey='en_US', 
     TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles');
    user1.profileId  =  p.Id;
    System.debug('Returning user '+ user1);
    return user1;
}

@isTest
public static void example1(){
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
    System.debug('Using profile ' + p);
    User u2 = buildUser(p, 'example1@sfdx-test.com', 'lm');
    System.runAs(u2){
        User u3 = buildUser(p, 'example2@sfdx-test.com','ceo');
        System.runAs(u3){
            System.debug([Select ID from User]);    
        }
    }
  }

}
```

The above example fails with:

```
UserTest.example1  System.SObjectException: Field is not writeable: User.ProfileId
                   /Users/user/Development/salesforce/sfdx-project/force-app/main/default/classes/UserTest.cls:11:1
                   /Users/user/Development/salesforce/sfdx-project/force-app/main/default/classes/UserTest.cls:22:1
```

What are the known limitations of System.runAs and why would we encounter such problems on a scratch org?

Comment: Please try to add some of the most obvious tags that cover big feature groups where possible. Also, can you please [edit] your post to include a question? Thanks!

Comment: #1 is hard to believe -- in my just-conducted experiment testmethods v45 with (or without) sharing happily create users given a valid ProfileId

Comment: @cropredy I add exactly the code I run. There is even an obvious bug (the email is not taken from the arguments of the buildUser but is hardcoded) but is not even the point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have as thoroughgoing and explanation as I might like, but this behavior is a consequence of `System.runAs()` enforcing system permissions against the new running user and presenting that enforcement in a way that's rather confusing.

[`System.runAs()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) is documented to enforce sharing but not FLS or CRUD:

> The system method runAs enables you to write test methods that change the user context to an existing user or a new user so that the user’s record sharing is enforced. The runAs method doesn’t enforce user permissions or field-level permissions, only record sharing.

However, system-level permissions are still applied, in the same way they would be if you actually ran the "outer" test as some user or another.

I modified your example class as follows:

```
@isTest
public class UserTest {
    private static User buildUser(String username, String alias, String profileName){
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name=:profileName];
        return new User(Alias = alias, Username=username, LastName='LM', 
                               Email='example@example-213213.com',
                               EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
                               LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
                               LocaleSidKey='en_US', 
                               TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
                               ProfileId=p.id);
    }

    private static void runTest(String profileName) {
        User u2 = buildUser('example1@sfdx-test.com', 'lm', profileName);
        insert u2;

        System.runAs(u2){
            User u3 = buildUser('example2@sfdx-test.com', 'ceo', 'Standard User');
            insert u3;
            System.runAs(u3){
                System.debug([Select ID from User]);    
            }
        }
    }

    @isTest
    public static void test_with_standard_user(){
        runTest('Standard User');
    }

    @isTest
    public static void test_with_sysadmin_user(){
        runTest('System Administrator');
    }

    @isTest
    public static void test_with_custom_user(){
        runTest('Custom: Sales Profile');

    }
}
```

(I found that passing `ProfileId` directly to the constructor eliminated the discrepancy in behavior between `without sharing` and no sharing declaration, for simplicity's sake).

I modified `Custom: Sales Profile` to add system permissions successively until I found one that allowed the test `test_with_custom_user()` to complete, then backtracked to identify the most granular change that determines success or failure.

It's **Manage Internal Users**. If the Profile of the current context user doesn't have this permission (or one that overrides/requires it, like **Manage Users**), the insert fails; if it does, the insert succeeds.

Comment: note in OP, mocked users were never inserted - whereas in your answer (which makes sense) they are. The OP using runAs StandardUser to create new users is something that never would have occurred to me

Comment: @cropredy I *believe* there's an implicit `insert` that happens upon `System.runAs()`, based on what some of the exception messages look like. I made it explicit for clarity. Open to correction on that!

Comment: wow - learned something new!